# python - replace a variable value in a line of a text file

Tags: python, user-interface, replace, text-files

I have a text file that assign a numeric value to a parameter with the following line:

```
designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="50")
```

I want to create a GUI in which user can assign a new value to parameters (for example 20). This GUI has to replace the new value in the previous line so that the result of substitution would be:

```
designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="20")
```

This is what i've tried to do:

```
import sys

from tkinter import *

def NewValues():
    diamValue = Diameter.get()
    cpValue = Cp.get()
    cbValue = Cb.get()
    gammaValue = GammaRel.get()
    epsValue = Epsilon.get()
    with open('parametri.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('newparametri.txt', 'w') as output_file:
         for line in input_file:
             if line.strip() == 'designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="50")':
                 output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="diamValue"\n)')
             else:
                output_file.write(line)
    return
def RunSimulation():
    pass
    return
App = Tk()
Diameter = StringVar()
Cp = StringVar()
Cb = StringVar()
GammaRel = StringVar()
Epsilon = StringVar()
App.geometry("250x200")
App.title("Static Calculator")
AppLabel1 = Label(text="Diameter").grid(row =0,column =0,sticky="W")
AppLabel2 = Label(text="Cp").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="W")
AppLabel3 = Label(text="Cb").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="W")
AppLabel4 = Label(text="Gamma Rel").grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="W")
AppLabel5 = Label(text="epsilon").grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="W")
AppEntry1 = Entry(App,textvariable=Diameter).grid(row =0,column =1)
AppEntry2 = Entry(App,textvariable=Cp).grid(row =1,column =1)
AppEntry3 = Entry(App,textvariable=Cb).grid(row =2,column =1)
AppEntry4 = Entry(App,textvariable=GammaRel).grid(row =3,column =1)
AppEntry5 = Entry(App,textvariable=Epsilon).grid(row =4,column =1)
Appbutton1 = Button(App,text = "Update Values",command = NewValues,).grid(row =5,column =1)
Appbutton2 = Button(App,text = "Run",command = RunSimulation,).grid(row =6,column =1)
App.mainloop()
```

Obviously, the results of this code is:

```
designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="diamValue")
```

Is it possible to correct this code to reach the goal?

Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="diamValue"\n)')
```

Your error is in this line. You need to concatenate/format your string.

Using concatenation,

```
myVariable = "world"
print("Hello "+myVariable+"!")
```

Using [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format),

```
myVariable = "world"
print("Hello {var}!".format(var=myVariable))
```

About string formatting, you should also check this question.
 [Pythons many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-deprec)

Answer (score 0):

As per Lafexlos's example instead of:

```
output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="diamValue"\n)')
```

You should concatenate the variable and the string like this:

```
output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="'+ diamValue +'"\n)')
```

or using the .format() method

```
output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="{0}"\n)'.format(diamValue))
```

You may need to format the variable as a string using the first example though: `str(variablename)`

Comment: Really i don't know how to thank you. It works! That's fantastic. The solution is: output_file.write('designPoint1.SetParameterExpression(Parameter=parameter1, Expression="'+ str(diamValue) +'")\n')