# Python TypeError: argument to string formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, typeerror, finance

I have been stuck on this problem for days now trying to figure out what the problem is. I keep getting below error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt 
from urllib import urlretrieve
%matplotlib inline

url3='http://hopey.netfonds.no/tradedump.php?date= 20150523&paper=AAPL.O&csv_format=csv'

year = '2015' 
month = '05'
days = ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24']

AAPL = pd.DataFrame()
for day in days:
    AAPL = AAPL.append(pd.read_csv(url3 % (year, month, days), index_col=0, header=0, parse_dates=True))

AAPL.columns = ['bid', 'bdepth', 'bdeptht', 'offer', 'odepth', 'odeptht']
AAPL.info()
```

Comment: now its gonna be closed as non-reproduceable ...

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the suggested answer.  The question should show the code that has a problem.

Comment: If you are going to change your story (and insert the placeholders) then you won't get that error message. And you want to interpolate `day`, not `days`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have *any* placeholders in `url3` and Python thus tells you it cannot insert the `year`, `month` or `day` values into it.

You need to use `%[formattercode]` strings to tell Python where to interpolate the values; `%s` will take strings for insertion (and you already have strings):

```
url3 = 'http://hopey.netfonds.no/tradedump.php?date=%s%s%s&paper=AAPL.O&csv_format=csv'
#                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Those 3 `%s` sequences tell Python to expect 3 values to be inserted there.

You also try to interpolate the *whole `days` list*. Use your loop variable instead:

```
url3 % (year, month, day)
```

Comment: @BhargavRao: and a suggested edit removed them again (probably an edit clash).

Comment: And can you add a small notice there that this kind-off string formatting is almost deprecated (pep 3101)

Comment: @BhargavRao: there is no official deprecation. `str.format()` is preferred, but the old format is going to be there for a while still.

Comment: @BhargavRao: [Pythons many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357)

Comment: Yep. That is why I said *almost* bout to be deprecated :)