# Python 3 Equivalent of '%' String Operator

Tags: python

```
import collections

Thing = collections.namedtuple('thing', 'color rotation direction')

thing1 = Thing(color = 'blue', rotation = 90, direction = 'south')
thing2 = Thing(color = 'green', rotation = -90, direction = 'west')

for t in [ thing1, thing2 ]:
    print('%s-colored thing rotated %d degrees %s' % t)
```

Trying to figure out the analogue of Python 2 `%` string formatting in Python 3. Of course the `print()` call above works in Python 3, but I've been struggling trying to figure out how to do it using `format()`.

This works, but does not seem very Pythonic:

```
print('{}-colored thing rotated {} degrees {}'.format(t[0], t[1], t[2]))
```

I tried

```
print('{}-colored thing rotated {} degrees {}'.format(t[:]))
```

but I get

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: The Python3 equivalent of `%` string operator is the `%` string operator. It has not been removed nor deprecated.

Comment: Why are you asking for an equivalent to something that hasn't been removed or deprecated?  If you want to do it with `format`, then do it with `format`, but `format` is *not* "the equivalent of the `%` operator".

Comment: My apologies. I thought I read that the % operator was deprecated in Python 3, but clearly I was mistaken.

Comment: It's ... complicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-deprec

Comment: Thank you, Robᵩ! So it's safe to say that format() is preferred, even though the % operator has not been deprecated. I'll use `format(*t)` as suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print('{:s}-colored thing rotated {:d} degrees {:s}'.format(*t))
```

Comment: Note that the `:s` and `:d` are optional.  OP's original version with the `{}` would have worked fine with the `*` operator on the tuple argument.

Comment: Very true. I added them because OP's original code used `%s` and `%d`.