# What are the advantages of these different string-formatting calls?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting, string-literals

```
name = 'John'

#basic method
print('Hello, his name is ' + name)

#.format method
print('Hello, his name is {}'.format(name))

#f-string literal method
print(f'Hello, his name is {name}')
```

All are viable ways to concatenate and outputs the same thing, but why would I choose one over the other?

Comment: Which one do you find the most readable?

Comment: Probably the first one, but are there additional functionalities by using the others?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-deprec and the linked questions within are highly relevant

Comment: Related and near-duplicate: [Pythons many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-deprec), and the older question [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 2):

#1 won't work if `name` isn't a string.

#2 is fine on any version but is a little unwieldy to type. Generally the best for compatibility across python versions.

#3 If the best option in terms of readability (and performance). But it only works on python3.6+, so not a good idea if you want your code to be backwards compatible.

There's also #4, old style formatting ala %s, %d, etc, which are now discouraged in favour for `str.format`.

Comment: all but #1 also allow the use of [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to tailor your output