# AWS MediaConvert could not identify region for bucket s3.Bucket(name='myname')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

my goal is to create a MediaConvert job from a given template by using boto3 with python: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mediaconvert.html#MediaConvert.Client.create_job

Apparently MediaConvert fails to identify the region of my output s3 bucket. I was under the impression that buckets were global, but even after some tinkering I wasn't able to fix the problem.

Here's the error message from the MediaConvert dashboard:

```
Could not identify region for bucket s3.Bucket(name='mybucket'): Failed to lookup region of buckets3.Bucket(name='mybucket')
```

The error code is 1404.

When I click on the Output Group on the dashboard for the job that failed, I get redirected to "https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/s3.Bucket(name='mybucket')/?region=us-east-1", which obviously fails to resolve a bucket. The correct path would have been "https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mybucket/?region=us-east-1".

Here is the code that triggers the job:

```
media_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name='us-east-1')
endpoints = media_client.describe_endpoints()
customer_media_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url=endpoints['Endpoints'][0]['Url'])
customer_media_client.create_job(
                JobTemplate='job-template',
                Role='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MediaConvert',
                Settings=...
```

In the Settings I use the following OutputGroupSettings:

```
                        "OutputGroupSettings": {
                            "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
                            "FileGroupSettings": {
                                "Destination": "s3://%s/" % target_bucket
                            }
                        }
```

I did verify that the MediaConvert jobs and the S3 buckets are all in the same region (us-east-1).

Any idea what the error is about? If you need more code, please let me know.

---

I have also asked this question on the aws forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=304143

Comment: does your bucket have a dot in its name? Also, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an known issue associated with the `%` string formatting operator used within a Python dictionary.

In commit Issue #14123: [Explicitly mention that old style % string formatting has caveats but is not going away any time soon](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3bbdc8e822b483fdfb66e0422e94630af10d1b80).

> The
> use of a binary operator means that care may be needed in order to
> format tuples and dictionaries correctly.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-depre) for more detail.

This explains why by taking the assignment outside of a dict resolves the issue. Consider using the `.format()` method to replace `%`.

**My Error Message**

I got the same error message from MediaConvert, but my issue was missing a `"/"` after the bucket name in "Destination".

Originally my code was:

```py
FileGroupSettings['Destination'] = 's3://' + bucketName + S3key
```

By adding a slash, it could locate the right bucket

```py
FileGroupSettings['Destination'] = 's3://' + bucketName + '/' + S3key
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by extracting `"s3://%s/" % target_bucket` into a separate declaration.

```
s3_target = "s3://%s/" % target_bucket

...

"Destination": s3_target
```