# I want to create a matrix of plots fetching data from a database for a list of antennas and channels

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

Plot switches horizontally when channel changes and vertically when antenna changes.

I am unable to switch the plots after plotting for a one plot e.g. 1,1 in matrix. The same data is fetched for the row and I end up getting undesired result.

```
    i = 0
    for antenna in antennas:
        ant = antenna[0]
          for channel in channels:
            channela = channel[0]
            query_test_run = "SELECT TestRunID FROM TestRuns WHERE DutID = '%s' and Rate = '%s' and Mode = '%s' and Band = '%s' and BandWidth = '%s' and Channel = '%s' and Antenna = '%s' " %(select_dut,select_rate,select_mode,select_band,select_bw,channela,ant)
    cursor.execute(query_test_run)     
    test_run = cursor.fetchall()
    print(test_run)
    for run in test_run:
        tstrun = run[0]
        final_query = "SELECT tx.Set_Power,tx.EVM,tx.TX_Power from TXEVM as tx, TestRuns as t, DUTs as d, APModels as a WHERE d.ModelID = a.ModelID and tx.TestRunID = t.TestRunID and t.DUTID = d.DUTID and tx.TestRunID = '%s' ORDER BY d.Serial_Number, tx.Set_Power ASC" %(tstrun)
        cursor.execute(final_query)
        data = cursor.fetchall() 
         if data != []:

            print(data,antenna,channel,run)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(channels),figsize=(30,5.5))
            df = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in data] )
            df.rename(columns={0: 'Set_Power', 1: 'EVM', 2: 'TX_Power'}, inplace=True);
            for i in range(len(channels)):

                for row in data:
                    row = ax[i]
                    channel = channels[i]
                    x = df['TX_Power']
                    y = df['EVM']
                    row.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are quite a number of issues with current code, consider the following re-factored adjustment that imports all your data and then subsets the data to plot according to corresponding *Antenna* and *Channel*. Specifically, below uses:

- [Explicit joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) (current ANSI-SQL standard) and not the obsolete, hard to read and maintain implicit joins with commas in `FROM` clause;
- [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) for **one** SQL query to avoid multiple nested loop cursor calls;
- Parameterization to avoid string concatenation (with [unofficially deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451) modulo `%` operator) and punctuation (enclosing strings with quotations).

  NOTE: Do not confuse parameter placeholder `%s` with the modulo operator's placeholder which is used by most DB-APIs (Postgres, MySQL) whereas others use qmarks, `?` (SQLite, PyODBC), and still others uses named/numbered (Oracle) placeholders each without quotes. Adjust per your actual database.
- Splits data frame using [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by each antenna and further by each channel for plotting.

Adjusted code *(untested and may need further adjustments)*

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ONE QUERY OF ALL NEEDED INFO (NO SPLIT OF ANTENNA AND CHANNEL)
sql = """SELECT t.Antenna, t.Channel, t.Bandwidth, t.Band,
                t.Mode, t.Rate, t.DutID,
                tx.Set_Power, tx.EVM, tx.TX_Power 
         FROM TXEVM AS tx
         INNER JOIN TestRuns AS t ON tx.TestRunID = t.TestRunID
         INNER JOIN DUTs AS d ON t.DUTID = d.DUTID
         INNER JOIN APModels AS a ON d.ModelID = a.ModelID  
         WHERE tx.TestRunID = %s
           AND t.BandWidth = %s 
           AND t.Band = %s
           AND t.Mode = %s
           AND t.Rate = %s
           AND t.DutID = %s 
         ORDER BY d.Serial_Number, tx.Set_Power
      """     
prms = [tstrun, select_bw, select_band, select_mode, select_rate, select_dut]

# BUILD DATA FRAME OUT OF SQL RESULTSET
sql_df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params = prms)

# SPLIT MAIN DATA FRAME BY ANTENNA
for a, ant_grp in sql_df.groupby(['Antenna']):       
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(ant_grp['Channel'].unique()), figsize=(30,5.5))

   # SPLIT ANTENNA SUBSET BY CHANNEL
   for i, (ch, chnl_grp) in enumerate(ant_grp.groupby(['Channel'])):
      ax[i].plot(chnl_grp['TX_Power'], chnl_grp['EVM'])
      ax[i].set_title('{}\n{}'.format(a, ch))             # PREFERRED STRING CONCAT METHOD

   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.show()
   plt.clf()
   plt.close()
```

---

To demonstrate with random data:

```
os_tools = ['windows', 'mac', 'linux']
data_tools = ['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia']

### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(11212018)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'Antenna': np.random.choice(os_tools, 500),
                          'Channel': np.random.choice(data_tools, 500),                          
                          'TX_Power': np.arange(0, 500, 1),
                          'EVM': np.random.uniform(1, 100, 500)
                         })

# SPLIT MAIN DATA FRAME BY ANTENNA
for a, ant_grp in random_df.groupby(['Antenna']):             
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(ant_grp['Channel'].unique()), figsize=(12,3))

   # SPLIT ANTENNA SUBSET BY CHANNEL
   for i, (ch, chnl_grp) in enumerate(ant_grp.groupby(['Channel'])):
      ax[i].plot(chnl_grp['TX_Power'], chnl_grp['EVM'])
      ax[i].set_title('{}\n{}'.format(a, ch))             # PREFERRED STRING CONCAT METHOD

   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.show()
   plt.clf()
   plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output 1]
[image: Plot Output 2]
[image: Plot Output 3]

Comment: this gives me an error "'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable."

Comment: Check the `sql_df` data. Any missing values in *Antenna* and *Channel* columns?

Comment: I added a random data demo to illustrate code should work. Any issues must be data-specific.

Comment: How do I deal with it if there are missing values?