# How to write attributes from an xml file to a text file

Tags: python, sql, xml

I am using ElementTree to get the attributes and elements I need from an xml file. The xml file is queried from mySQL
I want to write out all the attributes and elements into a new text file using python

```
    root = tree.getroot()
    name = root.attrib['name']
    country = root.find("country").text
```

I can see the results when I print them out
I want to write to a file the list of all the names and countries in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

So if you generate an array with all your XML name's, you can use this few line of code to create/write a `.txt` file and write all names on a new line.

```py
list_names = ["OLIVIA", "RUBY", "EMILY", "GRACE", "JESSICA"]

with open('listName.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    # filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % name for name in list_names)
    filehandle.writelines("".join("{0}\n".format(name) for name in list_names))
```

As @Parfait suggested, here is a solution without `%` to concatenate string.

Source : https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-lists-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: [The new `.format()` method is meant to replace the old `%` formatting syntax. The latter has been de-emphasised, (but not officially deprecated yet).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451)