# How can i concatenate a variable in the middle of a string?

Tags: python-3.7

```
us = getpass.getuser()  

path = r"C:\Users\<content of "us">\Desktop\Utenti"
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-depre)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way

```
us = getpass.getuser()  

path = r"C:\Users\%s\Desktop\Utenti" %(us)
```