# Tried to insert values from JSON file into MySQL using Python, why did my table turn up empty?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So I'm just trying to play around in MySQL to start getting some experience. I downloaded the Yelp dataset which is in JSON format. Since I already know Python, I figured it wouldn't be too hard to import the data into MySQL using Python because I couldn't find an easy way to do it with standalone MySQL. I set up a loop to add in the JSON row by row, and this loop ran for more than 12 hours. But now that I go to query the database in MySQL, the table appears to be empty.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews;
```

Returns a big fat 0.

I've tried querying different things to no avail--the database is empty. I've checked to make sure that the INSERT statement is correct with the given variables, and the string turned out to be exactly what it should.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import json
import os

db = mysql.connect(
    user=('root'),
    password=('{secret_password}'),
    database='yelpdb',
    host='localhost'
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

with open('filepath', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    data = json.loads(line)

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE reviews (review_id VARCHAR(255), user_id VARCHAR(255), business_id VARCHAR(255), stars FLOAT(2), useful INT(6), funny INT(6), cool INT(6), text VARCHAR(5001), date DATETIME(2))")

table = 'reviews'

with open('{path}', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(data))
        columns = ', '.join(data.keys())
        values = [each for each in data.values()]
        sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (table, columns, placeholders)
        cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

I thought--especially since the code took so long--that it was a lot of inserts, so it would just take a long time. But empty. It's hard for me to troubleshoot when it takes so long to do.

Comment: You never called `cursor.commit()`

Comment: @Barmar *faceslap* that is tragic.

Comment: BTW, you can write `values = list(data.values())`

Comment: @Barmar Appreciated. Thanks for helping a fool.

Comment: Avoid using the modulo operator for string format. [The new .format() method is meant to replace the old % formatting syntax. The latter has been de-emphasised, (but not officially deprecated yet).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451)

Comment: @Parfait thanks! That's really great to know. I hadn't heard about that!