# Is there a way with pandas to use read_sql() with an sql-statement, that takes multiple variables?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc, pypyodbc

this is a part of my code. I already have a database with values in it, and need to create a new dataframe based on the values out of this dataframe (at the moment these values are only 12 & 13, stored in the `header_row_ids` variable).

When I run the script, I get the following error message:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM dbo.TestDetails WHERE Id IN (?,?), (13, 12)': ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error')

Can someone help me fix this issue? I would be very grateful.

```py
import pypyodbc
import pandas

sourceConnection = pypyodbc.connect(
            self.sourceDriver +
            self.sourceServer +
            self.sourceDatabase
            )

placeholders = ",".join("?" * (len(self.header_row_ids)))
sql_source_detail_select = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TestDetails WHERE Id IN (%s)" % placeholders

header_row_ids = [12, 13]
header_row_ids_string = str(self.header_row_ids).strip('[]')

new_sql_source_detail_select = sql_source_detail_select + ", (" + header_row_ids_string + ")"

dataframe = pandas.read_sql(new_sql_source_detail_select, sourceConnection)
```

Comment: [**Warning**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451): The new `.format()` method is meant to replace the old `%` formatting syntax. The latter has been de-emphasised, (but not officially deprecated *yet*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) accepts a `params` argument that you can use to pass the parameter values:

```python
# header_row_ids = [12, 13]
# sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TestDetails WHERE Id IN (?,?)"

dataframe = pandas.read_sql(sql, sourceConnection, params=header_row_ids)
```