# Python SQL Date insert issue

Tags: sql, python-3.x, date, datetime

I am trying to insert a date inside the orderDate column in my sql database, which is of datatype date

```
date = (start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

testData.cur.execute("INSERT INTO customerOrders (orderDate) VALUES %s", (date,))
testData.cn.commit()
```

Here is the value of the variable 'data':

```
2019-01-01
```

Here is the data type of the date:

```
class 'str'
```

I am subject to the error of:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2019-01-01''
>   at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Add simple quotes in %s. MySQL needs to know that '2019-01-01' is a date type input.

```
INSERT INTO customerOrders (orderDate) VALUES '%s'
```

Comment: Do note: OP is attempting parameterization which uses the same symbol (`%s`) as Python's older string formatting method, `%`, which is [no longer recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451). Usually, you do not quote parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Consider parameterization of exact date time variable and avoid string formatting. Also, in SQL, `VALUES` clause requires parentheses enclosure around numbers or literals:

```
testData.cur.execute("INSERT INTO customerOrders (orderDate) VALUES (%s)", 
                     (start_date,))
testData.cn.commit()
```