# Using a list as parameters in a SQL statement using Python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a list `l= ['A','B','C'...]` which has a dynamic number of elements. I want to run the below statement in using SQL via Python.

```
sqlstr = "select * from [table] where ID in (%s) and column2=?" 
sqlstr = sqlstr % ','.join('?' * len(l))
```

However, when I try to run

```
pd.read_sql(sqlstr,conn,params=[l,parameter2])
```

There is an error

> **The SQL contains 4 parameter markers, but 2 parameter supplied**

I understand why there is an error because the list is parsed as 1 single parameter rather than individually. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `pd.read_sql(sqlstr,conn,params=[*l,parameter2]`?

Comment: [The `.format()` method is meant to replace the old `%` formatting syntax. The latter has been de-emphasised, (but not officially deprecated *yet*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451)

Comment: @pault, cheers that solved my issue!

Comment: @FeltonWang I also think `sqlstr = " select * from [table] where ID in ? and column2=?"; pd.read_sql(sqlstr,conn,params=[l,parameter2])` might work. If so, that's probably a better solution than using `'?'.join()`

Comment: @pault Thanks a lot. I tried without the .join but failed to work. Error with mismatching number of parameters.