# python list in sql as parameter

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am trying to pass a python list of integers in SQL components. I already looked in the previous questions but none helped me to solve the error. Here is what I am doing:

```
import cx_Oracle
SQL_Components = '''
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS materialize */
    xxx,
    xxx
FROM
    xxx
    INNER JOIN xxx
    INNER JOIN xxx
    INNER JOIN xxx
    INNER JOIN xxx
WHERE
    tpr.tpr_name LIKE 'M39AAA%' AND mml.mml_name IN (%s)
'''

def get_TPM_IDsDict():
    global chosen_lot
    chosen_lot=[]
    print ("Executing: get_TPM_IDsDict")
    f = open("XXX.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        chosen_lot.append(line.strip())
    chosen_lot = ["'%s'" % x for x in chosen_lot]
    Cursor.execute(SQL_Components % ("','".join(chosen_lot)))
```

I get this error:

```
Cursor.execute(SQL_Components % ("','".join(chosen_lot)))
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 580
```

Comment: first of all, What's your DBMS ?

Comment: you gave a SQL statement, so you're using a DBMS such as Oracle, Postgres, ... I've meant you tag that DBMS for the question. Btw, it's better to share this array within the question , not as a comment.

Comment: Looks like your query has more characters than what is posted. Do you have `%\'` anywhere in `SQL_Components`? This will cause the error you face.

Comment: @ShriramRamesh No I don't have any  `%\'` in   `SQL_Components`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider numbered parameters which `cxOracle` supports. Also, be sure to actually pass in parameter values in second argument of `cursor.execute`. Do not overwrite your very values!

And in all Python DB-APIs (`cxOracle`, `ibm_db`, `psycopg2`, `pyodbc`, etc.), parameter placeholders should not be quoted. Also, in Python generally avoid using `%` for string interpolation as it is [de-emphasised (not officially deprecated *yet*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451). Instead, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [F-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (Python 3.6+).

```
SQL_Components = '''
                 SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS materialize */
                     xxx,
                     xxx
                 FROM
                     xxx
                     INNER JOIN xxx
                     INNER JOIN xxx
                     INNER JOIN xxx
                     INNER JOIN xxx
                 WHERE
                     tpr.tpr_name LIKE 'M39AAA%' AND mml.mml_name IN ({})
                 '''
# BUILD NUMBERED PLACEDHOLERS WITH enumerate
prms = [":" + str(i+1) for i,_ in enumerate(chosen_lot)] 

# INTERPOLATE WITH str.format
Cursor.execute(SQL_Components.format(", ".join(prms)), chosen_lot)
```

Comment: For general reference the cx_Oracle documentation on binding multiple values in IN clauses is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).