# How Can My sqllite3 interaction be fixed?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get an admin account to edit a 'rank' (basically access level) for one of the profiles in my data-base. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/Python for SQL V_2.py", line 154, in <module>
    main()
  File "U:/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/Python for SQL V_2.py", line 9, in main
    start_menu()
  File "U:/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/Python for SQL V_2.py", line 22, in start_menu
    login()
  File "U:/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/Python for SQL V_2.py", line 72, in login
    Mek_menu()
  File "U:/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/Python for SQL V_2.py", line 108, in Mek_menu
    where Uzaname = %s""" % (NewRank, Findaname))
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "0rk_D4T4B453"`
```

The code that seems to be the problem is:

```
cursor.execute(""" update 0rk_D4T4B453.Da_Boyz
                   set Rank = %s
                   where Uzaname = %s""" % (NewRank, Findaname))
```

Originally, it was all on one line and it didn't work, and now I've tried it on multiple lines and it still doesn't work. So I checked here to see if anyone could help.

EDIT1: Thanks for the suggestions. None of them have fixed the code, but I've narrowed the problem code to: `where Uzaname = %s""" % (NewRank, Findaname))`

Comment: what is the table name?  is it '0rk_D4T4B453.Da_Boyz' ?

Comment: Enclose `0rk_D4T4B453` inside backticks or square brackets: `update [0rk_D4T4B453].Da_Boyz set ....`

Comment: @balderman The name of the database is 0rk_D4T4B453 and the name od the table is Da_Boyz in the example code it was database_name.table_name

Comment: @forpas Unfortunatly neither of the tricks you suggested worked, I've narrowed down the code that's causing the problem to: `where Uzaname = %s""" % (NewRank, Findaname))`

Comment: The error is: `unrecognized token: "0rk_D4T4B453"`, so it has nothing to do with the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please show a fuller code block including `connect` line. We need to see how database is assigned.

Comment: @Parfait , The connect line is either```with sqlite3.connect("0rk_D4T4B453") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()``` or                                                                            ```conn = sqlite3.connect('jpg26(//evesham/users/Students/UserAreas/Year09)/A-level Computor Science/Y12-13/SQL/sqlite/Databases/ork task/0rk_D4T4B453.db')
   cursor = conn.cursor()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use `ATTACH`, SQLite (a file-level database) does not recognize other databases. Usually server-level databases (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.) use the `database.schema.table` reference. However, in SQLite the very database file you connect to *is* the main database in scope. But `ATTACH` allows you to connect to other SQLite databases and then recognizes `database.table` referencing.

Additionally, for best practices:

- In `sqlite3` and any other Python DB-APIs, use [parameterization](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html) for literal values and do not format values to SQL statement.
- In general Python, stop using the [de-emphasized (not deprecated *yet*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451) string modulo operator, `%`. Use `str.format` or more recent F-string for string formatting. But neither is needed here.

Altogether, if you connect to the `0rk_D4T4B453` database, simply query without database reference:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/0rk_D4T4B453.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDERS
sql = """UPDATE Da_Boyz
         SET Rank = ?
         WHERE Uzaname = ?"""

# BIND WITH TUPLE OF PARAMS IN SECOND ARG
cursor.execute(sql, (NewRank, Findaname))
conn.commit()
```

If you do connect to a different database, call `ATTACH`. Here also, you can alias other database with better naming instead of number leading identifier.

```py
cursor.execute("ATTACH '/path/to/0rk_D4T4B453.db' AS other_db")

sql = """UPDATE other_db.Da_Boyz
         SET Rank = ?
         WHERE Uzaname = ?"""

cursor.execute(sql, (NewRank, Findaname))
conn.commit()

cur.execute("DETACH other_db")
```