# Formatting text. (Python)

Tags: python

I want to add the variable `price` into the string `txt`.

```py
price = 49
txt = "The price is ${}!"
print(txt.format(txt(price)))
```

I want it to insert it into the `{}`s. An error comes out saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kianc\OneDrive\Desktop\stck\this.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(txt.format(txt(price)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

and I don't know how to fix this! Any help would be great! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-depre)  You don't mention a python version.

Comment: problem is here: `txt(price)`. txt is string and therefore is not a funciton. You can't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt.format(txt(price))` attempts to call `txt` as if it were a function, when it is in fact a string, hence the error.

You probably want to be calling:

```
print(txt.format(price))
```

instead.