# Update on SQL Server table from Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

Following is the code in python that updates the records in the required database tables. Is there a better way to handle the same?

Read in SO that scanning dataframe row by row is a time consuming process. What is the better way to handle the same?

```
for index, row in outputData.iterrows():
    try:
        updatesql = " update table set [fieldname] = {0:f}   where dt = \'{1:s}\'" .format(fieldvalue , currentdt)
        updatecursor.execute(updatesql)
        sql_conn.commit();
except IOError as e:
            print ("({})".format(e))
            pass
        except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError) as e:
            print ("({})".format(e))
            pass
```

Based on the discussion below, made the changes but facing two problems.

```
 updatesql = " update table set [fieldname] = ? where dt = ?"  
 data = (outputData.reindex( ['fieldvalue'], currentDt,axis='columns').to_numpy())
 # EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND LIST OF TUPLES 
 updatecursor.executemany(updatesql, data.tolist()) 
 sql_conn.commit()
```

Problems
a) Date is constant and not part of the OutputData dataframe.
b) Float values are stored in scientific format. Prefer float values to be stored with precisions.

Comment: Before anything, stop using the modulo operator `%` for string formatting. This [method has been de-emphasized in Python but not officially deprecated *yet*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451). Instead, use the preferred `str.format` (Python 2.6+) or the newer F-string (Python 3.6+). (And actually you should be using SQL parametefization anyway for this question).

Comment: @Parfait, Updated my code. Thanks

Comment: Using string formatting to insert data *values* into an SQL statement is still a practice to be discouraged. Also, looping through the DataFrame row-by-row with `.execute()` is less efficient than `.executemany()` (or the SQLAlchemy equivalent in  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044758/2144390)).

Comment: @GordThompson, Please look into the latest statement. I no longer loop through it. But still looking for a way to format float values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `executemany` to avoid the `for`-loop by using a numpy array output via [**`DataFrame.to_numpy()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html). Below uses SQL parameterization and not any string formatting.

**With `iterrows`** + **`cursor.execute`** *(to demonstrate parameterization)*

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
updatesql = "UPDATE SET [fieldname] = ?  WHERE dt = ?"

for index, row in outputData.iterrows():
    try:
        # EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND TUPLE OF PARAMS
        updatecursor.execute(updatesql, (fieldvalue, currentdt))
    except:
        ...

sql_conn.commit()
```

**With `to_numpy`** + **`cursor.executemany`**

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
updatesql = "UPDATE SET [fieldname] = ?  WHERE dt = ?"

# ROUND TO SCALE OR HOW MANY DECIMAL POINTS OF COLUMN TYPE
outputData['my_field_col'] = outputData['my_field_col'].round(4)

# ADD A NEW COLUMN TO DATA FRAME EQUAL TO CONSTANT VALUE   
outputData['currentDt'] = currentDt
                        
# SUBSET DATA BY NEEDED COLUMNS CONVERT TO NUMPY ARRAY
data = (outputData.reindex(['my_field_col', 'currentDt'], axis='columns').to_numpy())

# EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND LIST OF TUPLES
updatecursor.executemany(updatesql, data.tolist())
sql_conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks. This sounds very promising. Will experiment and get back.

Comment: Great to hear. Did solution work? If not, what issues did you face?

Comment: how to use in place substitution but format the float values? In other words, if I don't format float values, all kinds of scientific notation is updated in the database.

Comment: added my updated code but it doesn't work. Let me know, how to fix the same.

Comment: See edits using `round` to match decimal points of column type and assigning date constant as a new data frame column.

Comment: Thanks. Will do testing and get back.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you could do it that would also take advantage of pyodbc's `fast_executemany=True`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

print(outputData)  # DataFrame containing updates
"""console output:
   my_field_col my_date_col
0             0  1940-01-01
1             1  1941-01-01
2             2  1942-01-01
…
"""

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)

update_stmt = sa.text(
    f"UPDATE [{table_name}] SET [fieldname] = :my_field_col WHERE dt = :my_date_col"
)
update_data = outputData.to_dict(orient="records")
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(update_stmt, update_data)
```