# How to combine Python function with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to define a Python function that involves rpy2 steps. This is my code :

```
from rpy2 import robjects
df=robjects.DataFrame.from_csvfile('mydataframe.csv')    

dplyr = importr('dplyr')
from rpy2.robjects.lib.dplyr import DataFrame

def boxplot(x):
        plot_df = (DataFrame(df).
                   filter('VAR1 == x' ))

        grdevices.png(file='boxplot.png')

        pp = ggplot2.ggplot(plot_df ) + \
             ggplot2.aes_string(x='VAR1', y='VAR2') + \
             ggplot2.geom_boxplot()
    
        pp.plot()
    
        grdevices.dev_off()
```

But when running `boxplot(24)` for example, I get this error  : object 'x' not found.

How can I mix the two ? It seems according to the doc that Python syntax ** could be a solution, but it is not clear on how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide fuller context including all assigned objects and modules with `import`. It appears you are trying to run a Pandas data frame through R functions which need conversion to R data frame. And Pandas `DataFrame.filter` does not filter rows by logical condition. Finally, in general Python even R, variables need to be concatenated or formatted to strings to be recognized, hence `x` is literally just `x` and not the input parameter value.

Comment: Sorry, I've added some context. In fact, my data frame is imported as an r object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
plot_df = (DataFrame(df).
           filter('VAR1 == x' ))
```

The string `VAR1 == x` will be evaluated as an R expression, but R
does not know anything about your variable `x` defined in Python.

If `x` is a simple scalar you could try to just create a string that
contains the value you want to filter on:

```
plot_df = (DataFrame(df).
           filter('VAR1 == %r' % x))
```

**note:** @Parfait's point about `Dataframe` is something I initially missed. It is assumed that this is a `dplyr` Dataframe, not a `pandas` DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Yes, my df is in fact an r object. I've edited my post with some context.

Comment: Consider avoiding the modulo operator `%` for string formatting which has been [de-empahsized in Python but not officially deprecated *yet*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451). Instead, use `str.format` (Python 2.6+) or the newer F-string (Python 3.6+).