# how to insert a dict in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there any way I can insert dict data to a sqlite3 column?
Let's say I have a table named `item` and I would like to insert co-ordinates like x and y which is a dict `{'x': 2, 'y': 4}` to the column name called `position`

I have given the datatype of `position` as `varchar` or `blob`.
In both cases it shows me
`sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :position - probably unsupported type.`
Is there any way I can insert value `{'x': 2, 'y': 4}` to `position` column? what is the best way to insert a dict?

EDIT

```
for i in range(0, count):
        item = {
            'player': random.choice(players),
            'floor': random.choice(floors),
            'position': {
                'x': random.randint(0, 17),
                'y': random.randint(0, 10)
            },
            'ts': random.randint(ts_2015_01_01, ts_now)
        }
columns = ', '.join(item.keys())
            placeholders = ':'+', :'.join(item.keys())
            query = 'INSERT INTO items (%s) VALUES (%s)' % (columns, placeholders)
            print(query)
            c.execute(query, item)
            connection.commit()
```

here c is the cursor based on `connection` on my sqlite db.

Comment: Have you tried serializing it to JSON? Then it would just be a string. That assumes you want to store it as an opaque blob of text; if you want to stick your `x` value into one column and your `y` value into another you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Can you show what code you use. In theory, what you want to do is definitely possible.

Comment: added sample code snippets in the original question

Comment: **Warning**: Stop using the modulo, `%`, operator for string formatting. This has been [de-emphasized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451) but not officially deprecated *yet* in Python. Instead use `str.format` (Python 2.6+) or f-string (Python 3.6+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other RDBMS's, SQLite does not have `json` types (the most analogous industry format to Python `dict`). Therefore, you would need to convert the dictionary to a string to store the object in a database table. Consider `json.dumps` for this:

```py
import json

...
columns = ', '.join(item.keys())
placeholders = ':'+', :'.join(item.keys())

item['position'] = json.dumps(item['position'])
query = 'INSERT INTO items ({0}) VALUES ({1})'.format(columns, placeholders)  # PYTHON 2.6+
query = f'INSERT INTO items ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})'              # PYTHON 3.6+
print(query)
# INSERT INTO items (player, floor, position, ts) VALUES (:player, :floor, :position, :ts)

c.execute(query, items)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: This is not working, I would like to insert this `{'player': 'Mark', 'floor': 'Fist', 'position': {'x': 13, 'y': 10}, 'ts': 1429077674}`  to my table `items`

Comment: Unlike other RDBMS's, SQLite does not have `json` or `dict` types. You will have to convert the `dict` to string for append to database table. See edit.