# UnboundLocalError on async function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that is taking arguments from a web form (optional, with default values).

```
async def _overall(ctx,region="All",mode="All"):
  await ctx.send("Running Stats... Region:  "+region+", Mode: "+mode)

  if os.path.isdir(latest_run):                          
    if region=="All":
      r="all"
    if mode=="All":
      m="All-Modes"
    jsonfile = latest_run+"/en/"+r+"/Week."+m+".json"
    print(jsonfile)
  else:
    print("Directory not found.")
```

When I run this, I get:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment

I have attempted moving the if statements to the outside, but it gives me the same error:

```
async def _overall(ctx,region="All",mode="All"):
  await ctx.send("Running Stats... Region:  "+region+", Mode: "+mode)
  
  if region=="All":
    r="all"
  if mode=="All":
    m="All-Modes"
  if os.path.isdir(latest_run):                          
    jsonfile = latest_run+"/en/"+r+"/Week."+m+".json"
    print(jsonfile)
  else:
    print("Directory not found.")
```

Please advise.

Comment: If region is not ALL, then r is undefined. Try using a debugger to go through your code line by line to see if r is defined by the time you use it.

Comment: You can use `region.lower()` rather than `r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code gets to here:

```
jsonfile = latest_run+"/en/"+r+"/Week."+m+".json"
```

It is possible that `r` and/or `m` are still undefined, because they only get assigned a value if `region` is `"All"` and `mode` is `"All"`. So, you ***reference*** them in that line of code before it gets ***assigned*** a value, hence the UnboundLocalError message.

The easy fix is to set a default value that does not depend on any inputs:

```
if os.path.isdir(latest_run):    
  r = "not-all"                      
  if region=="All":
    r="all"
    
  m = "not-all-modes"
  if mode=="All":
    m="All-Modes"

  jsonfile = latest_run+"/en/"+r+"/Week."+m+".json"
```

so that whatever happens they will always have a value when you ***reference*** them.

If you want it as one-line (arguably, to make it more "pythonic"):

```
if os.path.isdir(latest_run):    
  r = "all" if region == "All" else "not-all" 
  m = "All-Modes" if mode == "All" else "not-all-modes"                        

  jsonfile = latest_run+"/en/"+r+"/Week."+m+".json"
```

This kind of error is easy to understand when you use a debugger, which goes through your code line-by-line. It depends on your IDE, but I use [VS Code's Debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and I can see something like this:

[image: screenshot of VS Code debugger 1]

where I can see that by the time it gets to that code, both `r` and `m` are both undefined (it's not listed on the left-hand side under Local variables (hence the ***UnboundLocalError*** error).

This is opposed to when they are defined:

[image: screenshot of VS Code debugger 2]

As a final, unrelated note, look into [other ways of formatting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451989/2745495). Since the introduction of [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) in Python 3.6, that is now the preferred way because it's more readable than concatenating with `+`:

```py
jsonfile = f'latest_run/en/{r}/Week.{m}.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variables when the defaults *aren't true*.

You also shouldn't use string concatenation to generate filesystem paths

```
import os, pathlib

async def _overall(ctx,region="All",mode="All"):
  await ctx.send("Running Stats... Region:  "+region+", Mode: "+mode)

  r = "all" if region == "All" else region
  m = "All-Modes" if mode == "All" else mode

  if os.path.isdir(latest_run):                          
    jsonfile = pathlib.Path(latest_run) / "en" / r / "Week." / m / ".json"
    print(os.fspath(jsonfile))
  else:
    print("Directory not found.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! 

 jsonfile = pathlib.Path(latest_run) / "en" / r / "Week." / m / ".json"