# Limit decimal points in a float

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers

I am trying to limit my decimal places to 2 while printing the value of Pi.

Below is my expression after installing the match module in Anaconda Notebook

x=math.pi

print(float(x) (%2f))

Could you help fix the code/expression to print 3.14

Comment: `print("%.02f" % x)`

Comment: @MattDMo the `%` operator for format-strings has been de-emphasised. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/9946987

Comment: @sarema yes, I know. I was just blanking on the f-string format, and used the old style because it looked like the OP was trying to.

Comment: Thanks so much. :) It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

```
x = math.pi
print(f"{x:.2f}")
```

This is called an f-string. It formats `x` as a string of a  floating point number (`f`) with 2 decimal places (`.2f`).