# Is there a function under pyodbc that can replace cursor.copy_expert

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, csv, pyodbc

I use a code that opens a csv file to store it in a database. I use SQL SERVER.

when the file is opened in the RAM, after a processing that is done before, we want to store it in the database.

under Postgresql we use the following code but I want an equivalent under SQL SERVER

```
# upload to db
    SQL_STATEMENT = """
        COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH
            CSV
            HEADER
            DELIMITER AS ','
        """


    cursor.copy_expert(sql=SQL_STATEMENT % tbl_name, file=my_file)
```

I have no idea how to change the code block without changing the code

Comment: Are we still using the modulo operator for string formatting which has been [de-emphasized but not officially deprecated *yet*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/1422451)? Hopefully, you are no longer using Python 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas `psycopg2` is a Postgres specific DB-API to maintain extended methods like `copy_expert`, `copy_from`, `copy_to` that are only supported in Postgres, `pyodbc` is a generalized DB-API that interfaces with *any* ODBC driver including SQL Server, Teradata, MS Access, even PostgreSQL ODBC drivers! Therefore, it is not likely an SQL Server specific convenience command exists to replace `copy_expert`.

However, consider submitting an SQL Server specific SQL command such as [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#input-file-format-options) that can read from flat files and then run `cursor.execute`. Below uses F-strings (introduced in Python 3.6) for string formatting:

```py
# upload to db
SQL_STATEMENT = (
   f"BULK INSERT {tbl_name} "
   f"FROM '{my_file}' "
   "WITH (FORMAT='CSV');"
)

cur.execute(SQL_STATEMENT)
conn.commit()
```