# Formatting multiplication tables in python; not how to, just some explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, computer-science

I'm meant to make a multiplication table in Python using nested loops. I had trouble formatting it to make a table and looked for answers online. I came across a solution:

```
uplim=int(input("What is the upper bound of the multiplication table? "))
for row in range(1, uplim+1):
    print(*("{:3}".format(row*col) for col in range(1, uplim+1)))
```

and this solution works and formats the printed table correctly. I wanted to know why it works, specifically -   `*("{:3}"`   - what is that part for and what does it do?

I originally attempted :

```
for row in range(1, uplim+1):
    for col in range(1, uplim+1):
        print(row*col)
```

but it only printed one long column.

Additionally, my teacher's instructions say this:

> NOTE: The format function can be used to align your output.
> For instance, see the example below. '6d' means width of the value is 6 digits and type 'd' means integer digit. '6,d' means 6 digit integer with a , for every third digit from the right.
>
> ```
> >>> z = 1234
> >>> print(f'{z: 6d}')
> '  1234'
> >>> print(f'{z: 6,d}')
> '  1,234'
> ```

but I'm just not sure what to type in.

Comment: `{:3}` means "this value should be at least three characters wide, padding on the left with spaces if needed."

Comment: This code uses the advanced concepts of a *generator expression* in combination with *iterable unpacking* (what the `*` does). Better read the docs about `print` and its `end` parameter. With this you should be able to use your own code with minor modifications.

Comment: Also, this `"{:3}".format(row*col)` is equivalent to `f'{row*col:3}'`.  Your teacher is referencing [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) (also called "f-strings").  See also [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-depre)